# How to copy selected rows from one UITableView to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have two viewcontrollers where both have tableviews. The first viewcontroller has an image with a title in each row, while the other has empty rows. What I want is to able to copy the contents of the selected rows in the first viewcontroller and paste them into the empty rows in the second viewcontroller.

Here is the .m file:

```
#import "SimpleTableViewController.h"

@interface SimpleTableViewController ()

@end


@implementation SimpleTableViewController
{
    NSArray *list;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pic 1", @"Pic 2", @"Pic 3", @"Pic 4", @"Pic 5", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [list count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *simpleTableIndentifier= @"simpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIndentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIndentifier];

            }
    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
    return cell;

}

@end
```

I'm new to UITableView so I'm doing this for learning purpose.

Thank you

Comment: Copy data between your two data sources and reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is create a new NSMutableArray that is meant to store the values of the selected cells, and then pass that array to the new table as its data source.

Like this:

```
@implementation SimpleTableViewController
{
    NSArray *list;
    NSMutableNArray *selectedCells; // store the selected cells here

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // .... your code here

    // initialize your selected cells array
    selectedCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Now use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method which is available to you via the `UITableViewDelegate` to get the selected row data:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    UIImage *imageView = cell.imageView.image;
    // Now add whatever you want to your selectedCells array now 
    // that you have a reference to the selected cell.
}
```

With a simple setup like this, you can now pass your `selectedCells` array to your new tableView as the data source.

Hope this helps. I haven't tested the code, so its just to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

U could get the selected row as follow :-

```
//First TableViewController
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{
   secondTableViewObj = [[SecondTableView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondTableView" bundle:nil];
   secondTableViewObj.dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test",@"title",@"test2",@"detail", nil];

   secondTableViewObj.pass_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon"];

   //Alternative of this would be to use segue and do all passing of object's in prepareForSegue method but don't forget to put identifier.
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}

//Second TableViewController
In SecondTableView.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign) UIImage *pass_img;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dict;
@end

In SecondTableViewCon.m file

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *identtifier =@"yourCellIndentifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identtifier];

  if(cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identtifier];
   }

    //You need to provide tag value to your component in your xib/storyboard and set them with value's as below.
    UILabel *cellTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
    UILabel *cellDetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIImage *cellImg = (UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

   cellTitleLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
   cellDetailLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"detail"];
   cellImg = img;

   return cell;
  }
```

Anything else then do let me know.

Comment: Could you give me a small example of how to pass the contents of my cell to the second viewTable? I'm getting a little confused here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, here is the answer you probably want:

Use `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. In the view controller that you are copying *from* you must implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so `indexPathsForSelectedRows` can be part of an "inverse" in a way. If you know that index path is 1:1 with some member of your data set (and you will in all likelihood), then calling `indexPathsForSelectedRows` can get you the data you need by getting the index path and finding the associated data set member.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ...
 cell.textLabel.text = ((MyClass *)self.myDataSet[indexPath.row]).someTextProperty;
 ...
}

- (void)copyRowsToTableViewB {
    for (NSIndexPath path in self.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
         // Add to table B's datasource and re render
         [tableBDataSource.someMutableArrayMaybe addObject:self.myDataSet[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Now, it would be better and easier to copy the *data* rather than the contents of a view. For instance, create a `SimpleTableViewDataSourceAndDelegate` that implements the delegate & data source protocols given the appropriate service/ORM/whatever dependencies.

```
@interface SimpleTableViewDataSourceAndDelegate : NSObject<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

...

@interface UIViewControllerA : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
- (id) initWithBaseDelegate:(NSOjbect<UITableViewDelegate> *) baseDelegate dataSource:(NSObject<UITableViewDataSource> *)baseDataSource
```

This will allow them to share the same object being referenced when filling their data sources.